# Hack for fixed dumbbells

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, dumbbells, freeweights

I've found different ways to add smaller increments to certain equipment in our gym. For example, for cables (where each plate weighs 15 lbs), I place a 5 lb or 10lb dumbbell above the first plate. For fixed barbells, I tape a dumbbell in the middle of the bar with a kind of stretchable band with velcro.

The dumbbells in our gym have fixed weights at 5 lbs increments from 10 lbs to 30 lbs, and 10 lb increments for heavier dumbbells. Is there a way to add just 2.5 lbs or 5 lbs? I'm thinking about something which can be worn in the hands (weighted gloves?), wrist or forearms, and I don't know if there is even such a thing.

Comment: I have been using PlateMates for years. Then my gym replaced all their dumbbells with vinyl coated ones (maybe less damage to the floor when they get dropped), and PlateMates don't work on vinyl coated bells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can buy [dumbbell magnets](https://www.google.com/search?q=dumbbell%20magnets&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#q=dumbbell%20magnets&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&tbm=shop) to attach to the head of the dumbbells. I've typically seen 1.25lb magnets, though I suppose you can probably find 2.5 lb magnets as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did some Google searches, and I thought I might as well post what I found out as an answer. In addition to dumbbell magnets, there are also [wrist weights](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=wrist%20weight&rlz=1C1CHLW_tlPH464PH464&es_sm=93&biw=1152&bih=755&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=O4VhVNjPKYHFmwWZ34G4Cg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) and [weighted gloves](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=119175001).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Plate-Mates, a length of heavy metal chain might be a good solution.